# Update with a where clause with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, sql-update, where-clause

I have a column called `Sequence No`.  Anytime my java program receives a message, the message has a sequence number that is always higher than the last message.  When I update a row I need to check if the sequence number is greater than the sequence number in my database, if it is not I need to drop the message.  Something like `Update MyTable t where t.sequenceNo < SEQUENCE_NO_VALUE set  (t.sequenceNo = SEQUENCE_NO_VALUE, Set all my columns..);`  I have done this before with *SQL*, but never using *JPA*.  My other issue is that I would like to update the entire row at once. Something like this...

```java
public void saveWithCondition(Account entity, Integer sequenceNO) {
    EntityManagerHelper.log("saving Account instance", Level.INFO, null);

    try {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaUpdate<Account> update = criteriaBuilder.createCriteriaUpdate(Account.class);

        update.set(entity);//set the entire row instead of each column.
        update.where(criteriaBuilder.lessThan(entity.getODSSequenceNo(), SequenceNO));

        this.em.createQuery(update).executeUpdate();    

    } catch (RuntimeException re) {

        EntityManagerHelper.log("save failed", Level.SEVERE, re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what happens when you do that? Or when you just follow one of the many tutorials on the web http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/query.html#_criteria_api_update_query

Comment: The set method (that accepts a JPA entity) does not actually exist on the CriteriaUpdate object. I just put that in to convey what I would like to do. The tutorials I have come across have only specified how to set the values on specific columns. I am essentially looking for a way around having to explicitly name each column, and instead update an entire row based on my entity.

Comment: The set method takes a PATH. And it does not set "columns", it sets fields. And you have to set fields since they all have a value, which is individual to the field

Comment: @Kachopsticks: hello.. atlast how you resolved this... now am in same situation, in addition,  along with account i have child table as well.. i need to insert record into child when there is update on parent(Account)